# Using jQuery XPath selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I'm using a simple DOM parser function to catch XPath information of all nodes of a document

For example, the HTML is:

```
<div>
  <div>Everyday People</div>
  <div>My name is ACE</div>
  <div>Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Parsing the DOM to store the XPath info in the array `arr`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/js/xpath-selector.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_XPath(elt) 
{
  var path = '';
  for (; elt && elt.nodeType == 1; elt = elt.parentNode)
  {
    var idx = $(elt.parentNode).children(elt.tagName).index(elt) + 1;
    idx > 1 ? (idx='[' + idx + ']') : (idx='');
    path = '/' + elt.tagName.toLowerCase() + idx + path;
  }
  return path;
}

var arr = Array();
htmlDoc = document;
x = htmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{
  arr.push(get_XPath(x[i]));  
}
</script>
```

Later on in the script I use the values stored in `arr` to perform some functions like showing, hiding or changing content of nodes.

```
<script>
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
  //catch the object reference with the XPath info
  $(arr[i])

}
</script>
```

In the snippet above, I'm getting an object but I'm unable to get the object reference to use it for something like:

```
$(arr[i]).text();
```

Any help would be greatly welcome. Anyone worked on jQuery XPath selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if you need the Xpaths for anything other then selecting the elements. Because if you do not then you could store the elements themself in the arr Array:

```
var arr = new Array();
htmlDoc = document;
x = htmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;

for (i=0,b=x.length; i<b; i++){
  arr.push($(x[i]));  
}
```

Then you could do:

```
arr[i].text();
```

Comment: I know of this solution but I was wondering, if storing references to objects is more resource consuming than storing xpath informtaion.. sya if the document is huge, then storing the object references can be taxing on the resources and make the application slower...Am I correct ?.Please share you views...as I'm not a javascript expert

Comment: Making XPath "references" to objects will take *way* more resources than storing the object references themselves. An object reference is tiny in comparison to its canonical XPath string. Again - what are you really trying to do?

Comment: (And I only spoke of memory consumption here, not even of the processing time you need to recursively create XPath strings, and the time jQuery needs to parse them again)

Comment: Yes indeed, Tomalak is right. jQuery objects are quite small as they are just an array of refrences to DOMobjects (which are already in the DOM thus only stored as refrence) and methods that are stored in one central place. And indeed as Tomalak says, creating and parsing the XPath is quite resource heavy.

Answer (score 2):

The first question that comes to mind is... *Why* are you doing this?

You generate an XPath to an element and store it in an array so you can reference the element later on? Why don't you just store the element itself?

What are you trying to do in the first place? Looking at your question and knowing nothing else, I suspect there might be easier approaches than yours.